# Andengine tail to bullet

Tags: android, andengine, tail, projectile

Help me with the creation of the tail in the bullet. Effect should be like the tail of a comet. If anyone has an example please share.

Example in image http://www.android-apps-heaven.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/RocketBunniesv10two-300x180.jpg

Answer (score 2):

If you want to cheat, you can have a series of colored [alpha circle](http://www.thumbr.io/img/masks/medium-circle.png) particles emitting from the bullet. 
Each particle would have decaying transparency for the fading effect.
You would get a result similar to [this video at 0:30](http://youtu.be/19jtLuAZ7bw?t=30s).

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Maybe you have a example code on Andengine?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any examples